# How would I call this element via SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How would I call this element via SimpleXML?

`$xml->ls:viewMinutesThisWeek` definitely wouldn't work

```
   <ls:viewerMinutesThisWeek>5700</ls:viewerMinutesThisWeek>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ls` is a namespace, you need to filter elements that are of that namespace using the [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method. Try this:

```
$ls = $xml->children('ls', true);
echo $ls->viewerMinutesThisWeek;
```

Comment: Wont he need to register the namespaces first regardless of if they are properly declared in the document?

Comment: @prodigitalson: Passing in `true` as the second parameter as I have done will render that unnecessary.